# Why gcloud command fails on project settings

Tags: google-cloud-platform

````
Your current project has been set to: [myproject-1].

```bash
ERROR: (gcloud.init) Failed command: [compute zones describe us-east1] with exit code [1]
````

Can someone help with why I am getting this error? I am trying to reinitialize `gcloud auth init` and when I set the project number, I receive the above error. Do I need to change the project region to another region?

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: Which IAM roles does your account have? Show the entire command and messages when posting this kind of problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley Sure , I will keep my post with standard input and standard output, My Account had Owner & Editor roles, as i described by @ Ray John Navarro i had to used metadata command to update the zone " gcloud compute project-info add-metadata \
    --metadata google-compute-default-region=us-west2,google-compute-default-zone=europe-west1-b"

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates a problem when gcloud tries to define `us-east1`, which is a region and not a zone. The correct command to define the region would be

```
gcloud compute regions describe us-east1
```

If you are trying to set a default zone, you may put `us-east1-b` or `us-east1-c` as an example.

You can set the default field with the following command.

```
gcloud config set number/location[zone]
```

example command:

```
gcloud config set number/location us-east1-b
```

If the issue persists, please check if you have the proper roles and permissions for the project.

Comment: Thanks @Ray Yes i did set up to the US-West2 .  i used the cmdlet ( "gcloud config set compute/zone ZONE_NAME"   ) unfortunately  it did not work , now i understand why, so its region and not zone, i used another metada cmd to update my project zone

Answer (score 0):

@JohnHanley Sure , I will keep my post with standard input and standard output, My Account had Owner & Editor roles, Here is how to update zone using metadata

```
> gcloud compute project-info add-metadata \
>     --metadata google-compute-default-region=us-west2,google-compute-default-zone=europe-west1-b
```